# Exclude empty form parameters from URL with CActiveForm

Tags: javascript, php, forms, yii

I am relatively new to both **Yii** and **PHP** and I have some problems while composing **user-friendly URLs**.

I want to create an URL from user-entered parameters in a form which is an extension of **CFormModel**. I intially chose the **GET method** instead of POST because the user should be able to bookmark the URL in order to return to the same search results later on.The user must specify (at least) one parameter for the search but since there are many possible parameters in the form, I want to shorten the URL by **including only non-empty parameters** and their values, e.g.,

http://localhost/search/results?name=John&country=Ireland

instead of

http://localhost/search/results?name=John&family=&country=Ireland&yt0=Search

(If someone knows how to exclude the button ID and label “yt0=Search”, that would quite nice, too.)
I understand that passing all GET parameters to the URL is the standard behaviour of HTML forms and cannot be changed by using only PHP. Now I had the idea to add a **JavaScript function** that checks for all form parameters whether their values are empty after the form is submitted. If a parameter value is empty, the name of the parameter is set to an empty string (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271525/empty-get-variables-displaying-in-the-url)) which effectively removes the empty parameters from the URL:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var myForm = document.getElementById('form-id');
    var allInputs = myForm.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var input, i;

    for(i = 0; input = allInputs[i]; i++) {
        if(input.getAttribute('name') && !input.value) {
            input.setAttribute('name', '');
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure where to call this function (as opposed to “onsubmit” for a standard HTML form) and how to reference the form parameters since I am not yet familiar with CFormModel/CActiveForm.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the (simplified) form model:

```
class SearchForm extends CFormModel {

    private $_parameters = array (
        'firstName' => array (
            'type' => 'text',
            'config'=>array('name'=>'name'),
        ),
        'familyName' => array (
            'type' => 'text',
            'config'=>array('name'=>'family'),
        ),
        'country' => array (
            'type' => 'text',
            'config'=>array('name'=>'country')
        ),
    );

    public $firstName;
    public $familyName;
    public $country;

    public function getParameters() {
        return $this->_parameters;
    }
}
```

This is the relevant part of the view:

```
$elements = $model->getParameters ();

$form = $this->beginWidget ( 'CActiveForm', array (
    'method'=>'get', 
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false 
    )
);
```

This is the action part of the controller:

```
public function actionResults() {
    $model = new SearchForm ();

    $filters = array ();
    if (isset ($_REQUEST['name'])){
        $filters['firstName'] = $_REQUEST['name'];
    }
    if (isset ($_REQUEST['family'])){
        $filters['familyName'] = $_REQUEST['family'];
    }
    if (isset ($_REQUEST['country'])){
        $filters['country'] = $_REQUEST['country'];
    }

    if ($filters) { 
        $model->attributes = $filters;

        if ($model->validate ()) {
            // search action
        }   
    }
}
```

(I asked a similar but less specific question two weeks ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540058/shorten-url-by-removing-empty-get-variables-and-simplifying-variable-names).)

Comment: You might be better off POSTing your form to an action which then validates and redirects to a friendly URL to another action, which will render the results and fill in defaults for the missing fields. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Would you mind elaborating your idea in a separate answer? That would really help a lot.

Comment: I did as you suggested and it worked! Thanks again, I would accept this as an answer if it weren't a comment.

Comment: What's the problem with calling `myFunction` on submit? Additionally using POST to search is not a good idea. POST is used for creating resources on the server, you will have confusing API and as you said bad UI

Comment: @php_nub_qq, the OP wanted a bookmarkable url without all the parameters, like sort preference and user details.

Comment: @php_nub_qq, Interesting point regarding get vs post. I did some further reading and found http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating two actions in your controller.

```
class SearchController extends Controller {

function actionFormhandler() {

    $formValues    = $_POST;
    $argName       = $_POST['name'];
    $argCountry    = $_POST['name'];
    // and other statements

    // Now redirect
    $this->redirect(array('/search/results',
        array('id'      => $argName,
              'country' => $argCountry
    ));
}


function actionResults() {
   // do your thang here.
}

}
```

- The first action receives a post, from your form, and contains all possible data in the $_POST variable.
- The second action processes a GET, which contains the relevant URL components. This is your final destination, and is redirected to by the post handler action.