# How to make seo url for Yii $_GET method using url manager?

Tags: yii, yii-url-manager

I'm working on a site on local server. I have made a form to search country,state and city. After getting the results I see the URL formatted as [URL](http://localhost/yii_1/site/searchme?country=UnitedStates&state=Washington&city=NewYork)

I want to make this URL as [URL](http://localhost/yii_1/site/searchme/UnitedStates/Washington/NewYork)

So here I want to know about URL manager rules so I can make it as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this rule in your url-manager

```
"site/searchme/<country>/<state>/<city>" => "site/searchme"
```

Now, you need to have an action with this signature:

```
public function actionSearchme($country, $state, $city)
```

You can access `$country`, `$state`, `$city` from url inside this action. For example if your url be  like  `http://localhost/yii_1/site/searchme/UnitedStates/Washington/NewYork`, `$country` will equal "UnitedStates" and so on.

Comment: No that's not help me. I have update the code for
    public function actionSearchme($country, $state, $city)

Comment: Enter `http://localhost/yii_1/site/searchme/UnitedStates/Washington/NewYork` in the browser address bar, This will map to mentioned action.

Comment: Error 400, Your request is invalid.

Comment: [link] http://localhost/yii_1/site/searchme/UnitedStates/Washington/NewYork working now... just updated the url manager code with default one.

Comment: But this working if I enter the URL manually. How it will work automatically?

Comment: That's a different story. I posted answer sometimes ago. here is the link:[Shorten URL by removing empty GET variables and simplifying variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540058/shorten-url-by-removing-empty-get-variables-and-simplifying-variable-names/28541505#28541505)

Comment: That's awesome dude..You are the Man.. (Y) :)